# mysql: UNION GROUP BY without subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, union

I have a problem.
I want to wrap a query into a view. For this I have to transform the subqueries inside the FROM. My query is this:

```
SELECT 
    b.id, 
    b.summe, 
    getBauNrKomplett(b.id) as bauNrKomplett, 
    b.parent_id 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            pt.id, 
            pt.parent_id, 
            SUM(m.menge*p.preis_kostenanschlag) as summe 
        FROM menge m 
        join projektposition p ON (m.projektposition_id=p.id) 
        join positionstyp pt on (p.positionstyp_id=pt.id) 
        GROUP BY pt.id
    UNION
        SELECT 
            pt2.id, 
            pt2.parent_id, 
            null as summe 
        FROM positionstyp pt2
    ) b
GROUP BY b.id
```

I don't find another possility. I need to wrap the UNION statement because of the GROUP BY.

Does someone can imagine another workaround?

Thanks a lot and best regards,
Tobias

Comment: See DISTINCT. MySQL supports this abuse of the GROUP BY clause. It even optimizes it amazingly well, but it's not what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive this is equal. If not - could you provide sqlfiddle with some data and explanation?

```
    SELECT 
        pt.id, 
        pt.parent_id, 
        SUM(IF(m.menge IS NULL,0,m.menge*p.preis_kostenanschlag)) as summe,
        getBauNrKomplett(p.id) as bauNrKomplett, 
    FROM positionstyp pt
    LEFT JOIN projektposition p 
    ON (p.positionstyp_id=pt.id) 
    LEFT JOIN menge m 
    ON (m.projektposition_id=p.id) 
    GROUP BY pt.id
```

Comment: Perfect. It works with this code (derived fromm yours, only two little corrections needed). ` SELECT 
 pt.id, 
 pt.parent_id, 
 SUM(IF(m.menge IS NULL,0,m.menge*p.preis_kostenanschlag)) as summe,
 getBauNrKomplett(pt.id) as bauNrKomplett
FROM positionstyp pt
LEFT JOIN projektposition p     ON (p.positionstyp_id=pt.id) 
LEFT JOIN menge m     ON (m.projektposition_id=p.id) 
GROUP BY pt.id `